# input value with 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript

I'm building a calculator that takes 2 values from 2 input fields and runs a function for the calculation. The numbers that will be entered will be to 2 decimal places as they are prices. For example 35.84.

The results I'm getting are whole numbers and doesn't include the 2 decimal places. For example, if I enter 60 for (gas) and 34.84 for (price) my result is 17.00 and not 17.84

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```js
const calculate = document.getElementById('one');

calculate.addEventListener('click', calc);

function calc() {
    event.preventDefault();
    let gas = parseInt(document.getElementById('gas').value);
    let price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    let gasSaving;
    let result;
    gasSaving = gas * 0.3;
    result = price - gasSaving;
    console.log(result.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: well parseInt() makes an integer. So if it is a decimal, you want to use parseFloat or Number

Comment: 35.92 is a number no?

Comment: What is an Integer? "a whole number; a number that is not a fraction."

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of parseInt()